# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de crear una lista de preguntas en Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Necesito crear una enorme lista de preguntas (más de 100) que deben contestarse con CheckBox o EdiText (según el tipo de pregunta, que cargo de forma dinámica. Actualmente uso un ListView, pero he tenido problemas porque el texto que escribo en el elemento EdiText se pierde al cambiar de focus. He leído que usar EditText dentro de un ListView puede ser truculento, pero no tengo más opción que usar EditText. ¿Existe otra alertantiva a ListView que me permita cargar de forma dinámica un numero indeterminado de elementos?

Esta es la idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas utilizando un adapter para manejar los elementos de la lista?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar un `RecyclerView`con `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Si usas Android Studio, puedes crear un fragmento con una lista, eso te va crear por defecto una lista con RecyclerViewAdapter.  El código generado ya te da una idea como funciona, y si te quedas con problemas, preguntas :) Alternativamente podrías simplemente usar un LinearLayout vertical.

Comment: @Javier utilizo un ArrayAdapter

Comment: ArrayAdapter es tu `Adapter` sólo debes cambiarlo a `RecyclerView.Adapter` te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como implementar `RecyclerView` y `CardView` usando `Constraintlayout`. Aparte de ello `Realm` que es una librería de persistencia, funciona como `SQLite`. https://github.com/marlonpya/AprendiendoRVyCV/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: Podrias utilizar un objeto, dentro del adapter, que guarde los datos que el usuario introduce y asi puedas renderizar estos datos al momento que el sistema invoque la funcion getView